# Possible to call JSON array by an "or" command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a questions about JSON objects.

I have a .json file that looks like this

```
{
    "Plate Boots": {
        "T4": [],
        "T5": []
    },
    "Plate Armor": {
        "T4": [],
        "T5": []
    },
    "Plate Helmet": {
        "T4": [],
        "T5": []
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to put userID's into the [] of the objects by typing commands in my discord server. I am just wondering, what would be the easiest way to make a

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + " craft")) {
  }
```

command to put the message.author.id into the objects.
Let me make an example:

```
User1 can craft T4 Plate Boots, so he wants to be in the "Plate Boots - T4" category in the JSON file.
So User1 types in the discord server "!v craft T4 Plate Boots" (The !v is my prefix).
And the bot pushes his message.author.id into the ""T4": [*in here*]"
```

How would I go about making the

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + " craft")) {
  }
```

for this type of thing?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Try to narrow down the question so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. If format always will be like category its 2 worlds and type its 1 world, you can do it as follow.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const crafts = require('./FILEPATCH');

if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + " craft")) {
    let args = message.content.split(' ')
    if(args.length < 4) return message.reply('Incorrect format, use `!v craft T4 Plate Boots`')

    let category = args.splice(args.length - 2, 2).join(' ')
    let type = args[args.length -1]

    if (!crafts.hasOwnProperty(category)) return message.reply('Incorrect format, use `!v craft T4 Plate Boots`')
    if (!crafts[category].hasOwnProperty(type)) return message.reply('Incorrect format, use `!v craft T4 Plate Boots`')

    crafts[category][type].push(message.author.id)

    fs.writeFileSync('filepatch/craft.json', JSON.stringify(crafts));
}
```

Comment: you have done it again! Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Cipher. I think my explanation wasn't really doing to good. I have A LOT of this in the json. 27 to be exact and they all have T4, T5, T6, T7 and T8.

Like this
`"Plate Boots": {
        "T4": [],
        "T5": [],
        "T6": [],
        "T7": [],
        "T8": []
    },
    "Plate Armor": {
        "T4": [],
        "T5": [],
        "T6": [],
        "T7": [],
        "T8": []
    },`

But the code you wrote, wont let me be put in objects except T4 Plate Boots.

Comment: I think I have found the reason. Everytime i type !v craft and then followed by something with 2 words, it works. If the item in the JSON file is only 1 word, it wont write.

Any way I can make it so that it accepts 1 word aswell? For example "T7 Bow"

Comment: Hmm, whats is t4 , t5 in your code?